# 13.10 session-fallback-mode clock day/seconds

Tags: indicator, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 in an old computer that is too slow for unity, so I had to leave it in session-fallback-mode. 
How can I show day and seconds in the indicator applet ? it shows hour and minute only.

Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set a *custom-format* with the [gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html) command.

**1)** Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format custom`
- `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format '%A %l:%M:%S %p'`

In this example I set **%A %l:%M:%S %p**

#### Explanation:

```
    %a     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Tue)
    %A     locale's full weekday name (e.g., Tuesday)
    %l     hour, space padded ( 1..12)
    %M     minute (00..59)
    %S     second (00..60)
    %p     locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known
```

If you want locale's abbreviated weekday instead a full weekday name... you should replace the **%A** for **%a**.

More info in the [date man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/date.1.html).

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

As [Saurav Kumar](https://askubuntu.com/users/124963/saurav-kumar) says... this link might be helpful to create your custom string.

http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation. I would like to suggest one link through which OP can build the time format: **http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/**

Comment: @SauravKumar...thanks for the info. I edited my answer.